# Nodemcu does not respond to http GET request

Tags: php, http, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I want to send an HTTP GET request from my nodemcu to a localhost server. Both the nodemcu and my laptop are connected to the same Wifi network. Though nodemcu connects to the network, it does not send the request.
I tried sending the request manually and using "postman" and then it works. So I think the problem is with nodemcu code or something with device.
Any idea is welcome.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

/* Set these to your desired credentials. */
const char *ssid = "******";  //ENTER YOUR WIFI SETTINGS
const char *password = "****";

//Web/Server address to read/write from 
//website or IP address of server

//=======================================================================
//                    Power on setup
//=======================================================================

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);        //Prevents reconnection issue (taking too long to connect)
  delay(1000);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);        //This line hides the viewing of ESP as wifi hotspot

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);     //Connect to your WiFi router
  Serial.println("");

  Serial.print("Connecting");
  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  //If connection successful show IP address in serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  //IP address assigned to your ESP
}

//=======================================================================
//                    Main Program Loop
//=======================================================================
void loop() {
  HTTPClient http;    //Declare object of class HTTPClient

  String ADCData, station, getData, Link;
  int adcvalue=253;  //Read Analog value of LDR
  ADCData = String(adcvalue);   //String to interger conversion
  station = "B";

  //GET Data
  getData = "?status=" + ADCData + "&station=" + station ;  //Note "?" //added at front
  Link = "http://localhost/welcome.php" + getData;

  http.begin(Link);     //Specify request destination

  int httpCode = http.GET();            //Send the request
  String payload = http.getString();    //Get the response payload

  Serial.println(httpCode);   //Print HTTP return code
  Serial.println(payload);    //Print request response payload

  http.end();  //Close connection

  delay(5000);  //GET Data at every 5 seconds
}
//=======================================================================
```

The php code of localhost site is shown here.

```
<html>
<body>

status: <?php echo $_GET["status"]; ?><br>
station: <?php echo $_GET["station"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: connecting..... connected to:"****" -1 -1]

Comment: I can see you defining the variable `getData`, containing the query parameters. However, I don't see you actually using that variable anywhere?

Comment: I used it when I upload it to the nodemcu. Missed it in here. edited

Comment: When you say: _" to a localhost server"_, do you mean that your local web server are on the nodemcu device as well? If it's on another device (like your laptop), then you can't use `localhost` since that refers to itself (the nodemcu is calling itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localhost is a shorthand meaning “self”. You’re telling the NodeMCU to send the request to itself, though it probably doesn’t even understand localhost. You need to use the actual name or IP address of the computer you’re trying to send the request to. Localhost will never work the way you’re trying to use it here (sending a request from one computer to another).

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the same as localhost. 192.168.*** is probably what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Try To This :

```
<?php 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_REQUEST);

?>
```

Comment: tried this. still nothing. always get a -1 in serial monitor